# Linking columns until new values in column A

Tags: excel, vba

In the attached table I would like to link cell contents via VBA.

Column A contains contents that should be linked to the cells in column B until a new content is added to A.

The example in the attached table is shortened. The tables are much longer.
I have made a 'before' and an 'after' sheet.

The code I have is linked from A to B until a new value comes into A. But the VBA always takes the newest value in column B and not all the previous ones.

How can I adjust the code so that all values from B are linked to A until a new value comes into column A?

```
Sub Linking_columns_until_new_values()

    Dim arr
    Dim z As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets

        ws.Select

        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Resize(, 2)

            .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Font.Bold = False

            arr = .Value

            For z = 1 To UBound(arr)

                If arr(z, 1) <> "" Then
                    txt = arr(z, 1)
                ElseIf arr(z, 2) = "" Then
                    arr(z, 1) = ""
                Else
                    arr(z, 1) = txt & " " & arr(z, 2)
                End If

            Next

            .Value = arr

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Here is the link to the sheet: 
https://www.evernote.com/l/AGApoCGk-OJGKaHxwB2F-VCjO9uWJN299TM/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use VBA for this:

[image]

In B1, because it's first entry, I copied manually.

My formula in B2 is `=IF(B2="";"";C1&B2)` and drag down

My formula in C1 is `=B1` and drag down

Later on you could copy/paste formats, paste values, and then delete columns A and B. That way you would get what you got in `After` Sheet

Probably you can use the macro recorder to get the code and adapt it to your needs if you need VBA solution.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I know it is a simple fix with a formula. But I'd like to have a VBA solution for there are hundreds of sheets.